# The cost of texture2D in glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl

Quite confuse about this function
In the codes of glsl, I always see something like this

```
uniform sampler2D source;
varying vec2 textureCordi;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = textureCordi.xy;
    vec3 t1 = texture2D(source, vec2(uv.x - step_w, uv.y - step_h)).rgb; //2
    float average = (t1.r + t1.b + t1.g) / 3.0;
    //.....
}
```

In //2, the t1 save the data of the source(I think it is data), but how many data do it copy?
The coordinates of texture are between 0~1, assume that texture is an image
and the size of the image is 1024 * 768
the t1 would save 1024 * 768 number of pixels?
What would gpu do under this command?

If t1 do heavy copy job, could I ask the texture2D return
the reference of the source to t1(like c++)?

Comment: GLSL 1.2 specification : http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is operation per fragment, and for each fragment, with `texture2D` you sample single texel. Many parallel operations are done on gpu for whole primitive, and in some way, yes, all data is "stored" in the end in some output buffer, but each `main()` functions runs only for current fragment. It is unaware what's going on with other fragments, so every operation is per-fragment.

To clarify this further more, this should help, but it might be overkill:
GPGPU - http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~goeddeke/gpgpu/tutorial.html
Fragment shader pipeline - http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/fragment-processor/

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to your answers, t1 only store a texel not an array of texels.The gpu would perform the calculation per fragment, that is the way gpu manage the data?

Comment: It calculates per fragment, and texture2D runs with current data, not averaged data, and once calculation is over gl_FragColor would store that color in some output buffer at the specific location for that fragment. textuer2D would look at one, or few texels, based on interpolation method of sampling texture.

Answer (score 4):

The operation looks up exactly one texel, that corresponds to the texture coordinate you passed into (taking filtering, mipmaps etc into account). The texture coordinate is the normalized coordinate of the texel you want to fetch.

Edit: t1 holds the rgb value of the one texel the operation requested (as a vector with 3 components). The normalized texture coordinate is the input into `texture2D`. The following line calculates the average intensity of the three channels of that one texel, not the average of the whole texture.

Comment: Do you mean that t1 do not save the pixels data but the normalize coordinates of the texture?If t1 do not save the data of the texture, how could float average = (t1.r + t1.b + t1.g) / 3.0; get the average value of rgb channels?

Comment: @StereoMatching Of course it saves the data, but only of the single texel requested by the given texture coordinates.

Comment: @StereoMatching Christian Rau is correct, edited my answer to clarify this.